# What is the RKHS associated with the polynomial kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $K:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a positive-type symmetric function such that $K(x,y)=(x\cdot y + c)^2$ where $c\in\mathbb{R}$. We can write

$$K(x,y)=(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+c)^2=
\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2\\x_2^2\\\sqrt{2}x_1x_2\\\sqrt{2c}x_1\\\sqrt{2c}x_2\\c\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}y_1^2\\y_2^2\\\sqrt{2}y_1y_2\\\sqrt{2c}y_1\\\sqrt{2c}y_2\\c\end{bmatrix}
$$

Hence, I reason that $K(x,.)$ can be regarded as a function from $\lbrace1,2,3,4,5,6\rbrace$ to $\lbrace x_1^2,x_2^2, \sqrt{2}x_1x_2,\sqrt{2c}x_1,\sqrt{2c}x_2,c\rbrace$, and we can generate (and complete) an inner product space from $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

On the other hand, one can also write

$$K(x,y)=(x_1y_1+x_2y_2+c)^2=
\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2\\x_2^2\\x_1x_2\\x_1x_2\\\sqrt{2c}x_1\\\sqrt{2c}x_2\\c\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}y_1^2\\y_2^2\\y_1y_2\\y_1y_2\\\sqrt{2c}y_1\\\sqrt{2c}y_2\\c\end{bmatrix}
$$

Although this is a slightly more boring mapping (and there might be a clue there), similar reasoning to the above permits one to regard $K(x,.)$ as a function outside the aforementioned space, since a sequence of length $7$ is not in the span of $K(x,.)$ as previously defined.

By the Moore-Aronszajn Theorem, $K(x,.)$ is a *reproducing* kernel in exactly one Hilbert space. However, since a sequence cannot be evaluated at $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$,  it cannot be a reproducing kernel in either of the Hilbert spaces implied above. Which Hilbert space is it actually a reproducing kernel on?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer I've come up with to my own question.  I felt it necessary to try and show this, because most texts simply show there is a mapping from an original vector space $\mathbb{R}^d$ to one or more Hilbert spaces $\mathbb{R}^{d'}$ where $d<d'$, while failing to explain how $\mathbb{R}^{d'}$ is a function space, and waving hands while talking about reproducing kernels. While $\mathcal{H}$ is unique, the way it is defined can be generalised beyond $\mathbb{R}^M$, as StratosFair helpfully noted  - see the comments below.

**Proposition.** The function $K:\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto\mathbb{R}$  such that   $K(x,y)=(x\cdot y+c)^2, c\in\mathbb{R}$ is a reproducing kernel on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ comprising the set $$\big\{f:\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto\mathbb{R}\hspace{0.3cm} s.t. \hspace{0.2cm} f(.)=\langle x_f,\phi(.)\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M}|\hspace{0.1cm} x_f\in\mathbb{R}^M\big\}$$ and the inner product $$\langle f,g\rangle_\mathcal{H}=\langle x_f,x_g \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M}$$ where $M$ = $^{d+2}C_2$ and $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto\mathbb{R}^M$ is the mapping $$\phi([x_1, x_2, ..., x_d]^T)=
\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2\\\sqrt{2}x_1x_2\\x_2^2\\\sqrt{2}x_1x_3\\\sqrt{2}x_2x_3\\x_3^2\\\vdots\\\sqrt{2}x_1x_d\\\sqrt{2}x_2x_d\\\vdots\\\sqrt{2}x_{d-1}x_d\\x_d^2\\\sqrt{2c}x_1\\\sqrt{2c}x_2\\\vdots\\\sqrt{2c}x_d\\c\end{bmatrix}$$
$K$ is not a reproducing kernel on any other Hilbert space, and $\mathcal{H}$ admits no other reproducing kernel.

**Proof.**
Define a mapping $I:\mathcal{H}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^M, I(f(.))=I(\langle x_f,.\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M})=x_f$. Then $I$ is clearly a bijection. Furthermore,
$$\lVert f(.) \rVert_{\mathcal{H}}^2=\langle f(.),f(.) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}=\langle x_f,x_f \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M}=\langle I(f(.)),I(f(.)) \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M}=\lVert I(f(.)) \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^M}^2$$

Therefore, $I$ is an isometric isomorphism. Since $\mathbb{R}^M$ is a finite metric space, it is complete. Consequently, $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space.

Next, one can easily verify that for $x,y\in\mathbb{R^d}$, $K(x,y)=\langle\phi(x),\phi(y)\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M}$. Therefore, the set of functions $\big\{K(x,.)|\hspace{0.1cm} x\in\mathbb{R}^d\big\}=\big\{\langle\phi(x),\phi(.)\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M}|\hspace{0.1cm}x\in\mathbb{R}^d\big\}$ is in $\mathcal{H}$.

Now, for $f\in\mathcal{H}$ and any $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$,
$$\langle f,K(x,.)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}=\bigg\langle\langle x_f,\phi(.)\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M},\langle\phi(x),\phi(.)\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M}\bigg\rangle_{\mathcal{H}}=\langle x_f,\phi(x) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}=\langle x_f, \phi(x)\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^M}=f(x)$$

which shows that $K$ is a reproducing kernel on $\mathcal{H}$.   The uniqueness of the reproducing kernel Hilbert space associated with $K$ follows from the Moore-Aronszajn Theorem. To show that there is no other reproducing kernel on $\mathcal{H}$, consider for a moment the possibility that $R$ is another reproducing kernel. Then
$$\langle R(x,.),K(y,.) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = R(x,y) \hspace{0.4cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.4cm} \langle K(y,.),R(x,.) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = K(y,x)$$

The symmetry of the inner product and of $K$ in their respective arguments leads to $R=K$.

Comment: Nice, I think I understand what you were asking now. The point still stands that you could find many other feature maps $\varphi$ from $\mathbb R^d$ to any other Hilbert space $\mathcal H'$ such that $K(x,y) = \langle\varphi(x),\varphi(y)\rangle_{\mathcal H'}$ and get the exact same conclusion. At the end of the day you just get different, equivalent representations of the RKHS associated with $K$, which ultimately boils down to $$\mathcal H = \text{span}\{K(x,\cdot), x\in \mathbb R^d\}$$ (or its completion, to be precise)

Comment: Agreed, if 'representation' means an isometrically isomorphic Hilbert space. For $d=2$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^6$, $\|f_x(.)\|_{\mathcal{H}} \underset{shown}{=} \|[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6]^T\|_{\mathbb{R}^6} = \|[x_1,x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x_6,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x_6]^T\|_{\mathbb{R}^7}=\|x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,0,0,0,\cdots\|_{l^2(\mathbb{N})}.$  Furthermore, for $c=0$, $\mathcal{H}$ is isometrically isomorphic to both $\mathbb{R}^M$ and $\mathcal{S}^{d\times d}$ (see earlier link for latter).
 Of course, the notion of a reproducing kernel only makes sense on $\mathcal{H}$ itself.

Comment: Based on this, noting that a norm uniquely specifies an inner product and that every separable Hilbert space is isometrically isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, one can broaden the definition of $\mathcal{H}$ to $\big\{f:\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto\mathbb{R}\hspace{0.3cm} s.t. \hspace{0.2cm} f(.)=\langle x_f,\phi(.)\rangle_{\mathcal{H}'}|\hspace{0.1cm} x_f\in\mathcal{H}'\big\}$ with $\langle f,g \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}=\langle x_f, x_g \rangle_{\mathcal{H}'}$, for any $\mathcal{H}'$ isometrically isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $\phi$ s.t. $K(x,y)=\langle \phi(x),\phi(y) \rangle_{\mathcal{H}'}$.

Comment: The equivalences above are generally noted, but the nature of the link to the unique RKHS associated with $K$ tends to be underplayed. Of course, the notion of a reproducing kernel only makes sense on a space of functions. In *Foundations of Machine Learning* (2018), Mohri et al give learning guarantees for kernel-based support vector machines, appealing to the reproducing property of $K$ on a high-dimensional space that doesn't have any functions! References to the RKHS are therefore implicit, which can make reading the proofs pretty confusing without awareness of the equivalences.

Comment: P.S. Where a bijection between $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{H}'$ cannot be established, the isometric isomorphism is *into*, rather than *onto*, $\mathcal{H}'$.  Thus I'd venture that the feature space with the least possible dimensionality for a given kernel is the one where the isometric isomorphism is *onto*. In the case of the polynomial kernel on $\mathbb{R}^d$, this would be a feature space of $M$ dimensions, such as $\mathbb{R}^M$. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> Hence, I reason that $K(x,\cdot)$ can be regarded as a function from $\lbrace1,2,3,4,5,6\rbrace$ to $\lbrace x_1^2,x_2^2, \sqrt{2}x_1x_2,\sqrt{2c}x_1,\sqrt{2c}x_2,c\rbrace$

This sentence doesn't make much sense, I assume you meant that $K(x,\cdot)$ can be regarded as a function from $\mathbb R^6$ to $\mathbb  R^6$, right ? If that's what you meant, then it is wrong.

In both cases, what you've shown is that there exist two distinct **feature maps** $\phi : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^6$ and $\varphi : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^7$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^2$ :
$$K(x,y) = \langle\phi(x),\phi(y)\rangle = \langle\varphi(x),\varphi(y)\rangle $$
As you've just shown, feature maps need not be unique (in fact you could split the terms in the expression of $K(x,y)$ further and come up with feature mappings to arbitrarily large dimension), but the point is that regardless, $K$ is still defined on $\mathbb R^2$, and therefore the RKHS associated with $K$ is given by the completion of $\text{span}\lbrace K(x,\cdot)\mid x\in \mathbb R^2\rbrace $ which is a Hilbert space of functions defined on $\mathbb R^2$, and there is no contradiction with Moore–Aronszajn theorem.

The existence of feature maps is what make [kernel methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) so popular in practical applications : they allow us to implicitly map our low dimensional data to a much higher dimensional space where the problem is easier to solve, with no extra computational expense.

Comment: I define $K$ as a real-valued positive-type kernel on the product space $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$. While it adds ambiguity, this designation is typically used in order to reflect the symmetry of such kernels. Of course, fixing the first argument renders it a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and defines a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to a Hilbert space.

Comment: On a separate point, I'm not implying the Moore-Aronszajn theorem is being contradicted. I'm just wondering how to tell whether we're working in the actual RKHS for a given kernel or simply an arbitrary feature space.  I have since found a construction process for the polynomial kernel here: https://members.cbio.mines-paristech.fr/~jvert/svn/kernelcourse/slides/master2017/master2017.pdf. This makes it easier to unpick claims that might be made in relation to a particular feature space chosen for a given kernel.

Comment: Actually, the link above shows construction of the RKHS space associated with the "affine" kernel $K(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle_{\mathbb{R}^d}^2, x,y\in\mathbb{R}^d$.  This involves an isometric isomorphism with the Hilbert space $\mathcal{S}^{d\times d}$ of symmetric matrices in $\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d$.  I will generalise a bit below.

Comment: So for the domain on which $K$ is defined, I don't really distinguish between considering $K$ as a map on $X\times X$ or $K(x,\cdot)$ as a map on $X$, as I assume it is clear from context. The point of my answer was that even if there are feature maps $\phi$ which represent $K(x,y)$ as $\phi(x)\cdot\phi(y)$ (and there indeed are infinitely many), $K(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a reproducing kernel on $X\times X$ and **not** on $\phi(X)\times \phi(X)$. If that doesn't answer your question then I'm not sure of what you're asking, so feel free to edit your question or write an answer directly.

Comment: Yes, there's a slight ambiguity. I agree that whether one defines $K$ on the product space or not is fairly irrelevant - I just follow standard usage where a positive-type kernel is introduced as a function per se, without initially bringing in any kind of structure.  The ambiguity is this: $K$ is a function on $X$ (or $X\times X$), but is a reproducing kernel in a unique Hilbert space of functions. I wouldn't like to say whether $\phi()$ always  maps X into a space isometrically isomorphic to $H$, though it seems to in this case.  All this is abridged in most data-orientated texts!